# Using QuickOSM in model designer QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I am trying to create a model in QGIS using the model designer but having difficulties with the QuickOSM features.

My goal is to:
Create three buffers (2km, 3km, 6km) around a multi point feature.

- this part was successful. Input (Multi point feature) + algorithm (buffer)

The next step which I am struggling with is to link the buffer outputs and search within each of these buffer areas for different objects using QuickOSM.

To add more context:
My multipoint objects area wind turbines (previous step)
I would like to search for

- Windturbines in the 6km buffer area
- Farmyard and industrial land cover in the 3km buffer area
- Buildings in the 2km buffer area

I am not sure which is the most appropriate option to choose from here
[image]

I am also unsure what the correct parameters are here:
[image]

I am not sure how to link the QuickOSM to the previous buffer outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Build query inside an extent". You can then hook this up to your Buffered output:

[image]

If you use "Build query inside an area", you need to supply a description of an area (eg a suburb, city, state etc). This is similar to using QuickOSM directly with the "In" drop down eg:

[image]